# How to join or left join three tables to get a piece of data from one of the tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a users table, a jobs table, and a files table; the exact table names are `user_table`, `jobs`, and `files`.

The files table and jobs table have a common field, and the jobs table and users table have a common field, but all 3 do not have a common field. So files table has `jobid` which equals `id` from jobs table, and jobs table has `userid` which equals `userid` from users table.

Example records

```
files table

id    name        path                jobid
-------------------------------------------
7     test.gif    uploads/test.gif    130

jobs table

id     userid    ponumber    date
------------------------------------------------
130    1013      2322        10/14/2013 2:55:1pm

user_table table

userid    username    email              fname    sname
-------------------------------------------------------
1013      username    email@email.com    first    last
```

File 7 belongs to job 130, and job 130 belongs to user 1013. So when displaying files on a page, I want to also display the owner of the file, but that's two tables away.

How can I do this? I haven't tried anything because I am new to MySQL programming. If I were to try and guess something, it might go something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_table u
INNER JOIN jobs j USING (userid)
LEFT JOIN files f ON j.id = f.jobid
```

which probably is such a wild guess, it's not even worth mentioning.

Comment: this is what ended up working.  not sure i picked the right answer as correct.  i probably should have mentioned that even though i'm selecting multiple columns from multiple tables, that it needs to bring back one row based off of one record from the files table.

    SELECT files.*, jobs.*, user_table.* FROM files LEFT JOIN jobs ON files.jobid = jobs.id LEFT JOIN user_table ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid WHERE files.id=$id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if all users have jobs and all jobs have files OR you want to only show users with jobs that have files then

```
SELECT *
FROM user_table u
INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id=u.userID
INNER JOIN files f ON j.id = f.jobid
```

will do that.

If all users **DON'T** have jobs and all jobs **DON'T** have files OR you want to show all users regardless if they have a job with files or not then

```
SELECT *
FROM user_table AS u
LEFT JOIN jobs AS j ON j.id=u.userID
LEFT JOIN files AS f ON j.id = f.jobid
```

will do that.

[HERE](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) goes a description of joins that might help you understand joins a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_table.username, files.*
FROM files 
INNER JOIN jobs ON files.jobid = jobs.id
INNER JOIN user_table ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT files.id, files.name, jobs.id, user_table.username
FROM files LEFT JOIN jobs
ON files.id = jobs.id LEFT JOIN user_table
ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid
```